# How can I output a 64-bit value in windbg?

Tags: c++, winapi, windbg

I'm trying to create my own extension for WinDbg, and I need to output a 64-bit value to the WinDbg console.

This is my code:

```
        #include <dbgeng.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
        
            uint64_t val = 0x1234567890abcdef;
    ////code for ptrIDebugControl...
            ptrIDebugControl->Output(DEBUG_OUTCTL_ALL_CLIENTS, "%" PRIx64 "\n", val);
```

I am getting this(90abcdef) number despite the fact that I am using PRIx64 macros

Comment: Did you look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/dbgeng/nf-dbgeng-idebugcontrol-output) for `IDebugControl::Output` ? I don't think it supports a full printf-style interface.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, thanks! I just thought that it supports everything since the same %x works fine

Comment: Use %I64X.    Out("%I64X%I64x %X\n",InstructionOffset,ScopeFrame.InstructionOffset,ScopeContext.Eip);